# Third Party Cookie browser restriction - Tableau Embedded view

Tags: cookies, tableau-api, p3p

I have few dashboard created in tableau. I am embeddeing these dashboard in a ASP.NET web page and providing it to my customers. The tableau trusted authentication has been implemented to get the ticket from tableau and render the visualizations. Everything works fine and there are no issues in rendering or accessing the visualizations.

However for some customers, I get the third party cookie error. The visualization is not being shown. In this case, however, the browser treats the cookie as a third-party cookie. This is because the cookie is set with a domain that's different from the one shown in the browser's address bar.

If I modify the privacy settings to allow the third party cookies, then the visualizations are showing up. Else I am having a tableau signin page shown in my embedded view.

My problem is, I cant go to my customer and ask to allow the third party cookies. The reason is, they are not willing to change the privacy settings and for some people, it has been configured by their organization.

I came to know about P3P header policy in IIS. However, it seems Safari browser will not support this. I want the cookie to get unblocked in Internet explorer, Chrome and Safari.

As per one article it states that the below P3P header needs to be added under the system.webserver in my webconfig

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="P3P" value='CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"'/>
```

But to implement this, the following files are needed.

- Full privacy policy for the site in an XML file, according to the P3P
  specification.
- A policy reference file in XML format with a file name of P3p.xml,
  according to the P3P specification. This policy reference file must
  refer to the full privacy policy for your Web site.
- The compact codes for the privacy policy, to be added as mini
  headers.

From where I can generate the policies files provided above. Is there any free service available to generate the policy files.

Also Is there any other way for this? Without changing the privacy and cookie setting, will I be able to do it through an alternative way?

Comment: We've had similar issues with Tableau here. Have you set your P3P properly? https://grack.com/blog/2010/01/06/3rd-party-cookies-dom-storage-and-privacy/

Comment: @Adrianopolis Nope I haven't set any P3P headers in my site. Also i need to implement this for 3 different browsers internet explorer, chrome and safari. I heard setting P3P will not work in safari.

Comment: Look into the various P3P options on the link I referred you to. If those don't suite your case do a little research on P3P for third party cookies and I'm sure you will come up with more info.